# Real Analysis: Prove the set of accumulation points in closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I was hoping someone could help me check this proof:

Given $E \subset \Bbb{R}$, define $E'$ as the set of all the accumulation points of $E$.

Prove that $E'$ is closed.

**Proof:**
Let us assume the contrary: that $E'$ is not closed. Therefore  there exists some $ x $ that is an accumulation point for $E'$ but $x \notin E'$.

If $x$ is an accumulation point of $E'$, this implies that

$$ \forall \delta > 0:V'(x,\delta) \cap E' \ne \emptyset $$
Where $V'(x,\delta)$ is the $\delta$ - neighborhood around $x$, not including $x$

$$V'(x,\delta)= V(x,\delta) \setminus \{x\}  =( x - \delta, x) \cup (x, x + \delta )$$

$V'(x,\delta) \cap E' \ne \emptyset$ either on the first interval or on the second interval. Without loss of generality I will assume that $V'(x,\delta) \cap E' \ne \emptyset$ on the second interval: $ \forall \delta: (x,x+\delta) \cap E' \ne \emptyset$.

The interval that intersects with $E'$ therefore contains points in $E'$, so those points are accumulation points of $E$.

Now I wil show that

$$ \forall \delta > 0 : (x,x+\delta) \cap E \ne \emptyset$$

Assume

$$ \exists \delta > 0: (x,x+\delta) \cap E = \emptyset$$

And Let:

$$y \in (x,x+\delta)$$

$$ \exists \epsilon: \epsilon = min\{y-x,x+\delta - y\}$$

so

$$ ( y-\epsilon, y ) \cup ( y, y + \epsilon ) = V'(y,\epsilon) \subset (x, x+\delta ) $$

It follows from the previous assumption:

$$ (x,x+\delta) \cap E = \emptyset \implies V'(y, \epsilon ) \cap E = \emptyset $$

Therefore $y$ is not an accumulation point of $E$ for any $y \in (x, x+\delta)$. But we know that there are and infinite number of accumulation points of $E$ on that interval. So the assumption that $ \exists \delta > 0 : (x,x+\delta) \cap E = \emptyset$ must be incorrect. So,

$$ \forall \delta > 0 : (x,x+\delta) \cap E \ne \emptyset$$

And using a similar argument for the case if $ (x-\delta,x) \cap E' \ne \emptyset$

we now have

$$ \forall \delta > 0 : V'(x,\delta) \cap E \ne \emptyset$$

So $x$ is an accumulation point of $E$ and should be in $E'$, but for the original contradiction we assumed that $x \notin E'$. So if $x$ is an accumulation point of $E'$ then $x \in E'$. Thus concluding the proof that $E'$ is closed.

$$$$

Answer (score 1):

It's fine. Just be more careful about the quantifiers.

The negation of $$\forall \delta > 0: (x, x + \delta) \cap E' \neq \emptyset $$

is

$$\exists \delta > 0: (x, x + \delta) \cap E' = \emptyset $$

Comment: Thanks so much for that, yes these kind of things I need to pay attention to.